# Is there a way to change the autogenerated shema name of a serializer in drf-spectacular

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, openapi, drf-spectacular

I got many serializers named 'InputSerializer' and 'OutputSerializer' which translates to 'Input' and 'Output' schema name in drf-spectacular. This ends up referring the api endpoints to the same schema. Is there a way to override the autogenerated schema names of these serializers without changing the name of the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this a bunch, but never tried to solve it.  Looking at the docs I found [`extended_schema_serializer`](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html#step-4-extend-schema-serializer), which might do what you need.  Here is the [full api](https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_spectacular.html#drf_spectacular.utils.extend_schema_serializer), and the relevant point:

- `component_name` – override default class name extraction

```
@extended_schema_serializer(component_name="SomeNiceReallyLongId")
class Input(Serializer):
    # pass
```

Its kinda long and ugly, but that can be fixed by a decorator on the decorator :D

**Edit**:

I ended up implementing this.  Here is the small wrapper I wrote.  It just makes things shorter and consistent between serializers and fields.

You can use `extended_schema_serializer` more than once on a serializer, so this won't break anything.

```
@oapi.name("UserEditRequest")
@extend_schema_serializer(examples=[]) # other settings
class EditSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    pass
```

```
# oapi.py
from drf_spectacular.utils import set_override as _set_override

def name(val: str):
    def decorator(klass):
        if issubclass(klass, BaseSerializer):
            _set_override(klass, "component_name", val)
        elif isinstance(klass, Field):
            _set_override(klass, "field_component_name", val)
        else:
            raise Exception(f"Unhandled class: {klass}")

        return klass

    return decorator
```

Comment: Well your solution works! But it's too bloated to be used practically (for my usecase), so I'm probably gonna ditch drf-spectacular in favor of slatedocs

Comment: You can always write a wrapper such that you have `uniq_it("LongName")`, but I see your frustration.  Slatedos is manual API documentation, so its a different thing.  Autodocumentation is nice sometimes, but we just share it with internal devs and do the same thing you are doing for anything external.

Answer (score 3):

Understandable, but a unique name has to come from somewhere and spectacular cannot know what is a good name for you other than the classname itself.
Andrew provides the native solution but there is also syntactic sugar for that (compatibility feature with drf-yasg).

```py
class InputSerializer(serializer.Serializer):

    class Meta:
        ref_name = 'SomeNiceReallyLongId'
```

https://drf-spectacular.readthedocs.io/en/latest/drf_yasg.html?highlight=ref_name#compatibility

Otherwise I would recommend subclassing `AutoSchema` and overriding `_get_serializer_name` and make it work for you.